# Console input no longer being echo'd after changing stdout

Tags: java, stdout, stdin

In my program I have changed stdout using `System.setOut();` but after that, typing into the console no longer echoes the input back.

I tried the following, with no avail:

```
originalStdIn = System.in;
stdIn = new InputStream() {
    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
        return originalStdIn.available();
    }
    
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int chr = originalStdIn.read();
        stdOut.write(chr);
        return chr;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int read(byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
        return this.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int read(byte[] buffer, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int readResult = originalStdIn.read(buffer, off, len);
        stdOut.write(buffer, off, readResult);
        return readResult;
    }
};
System.setIn(stdIn);
```

This is how I read input:

```
private void handleThread_func() {
    Logging.didUpdateInWindow = true;
    System.out.print(this.consoleInputPrefix);
    
    while (!this.isClosed) {
        try {
            if (System.in.available() > 0) {
                String input = "";
                while (System.in.available() > 0) {
                    input += this.inputReader.readLine();
                }
                this.handleInput(input);
                
                Logging.didUpdateInWindow = true;
                System.out.print(this.consoleInputPrefix);
            }
            
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ex instanceof InterruptedException) break;
    Logging.logSevere("Unable to handle console input: " + 
            Utils.getExceptionStackTraceAsStr(ex));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing `input += this.inputReader.readLine();` to `input += (char)this.inputReader.read()` but while it did echo, the input was read in the incorrect order